# how to change the existing printed line in AWK

Tags: unix, script, awk

when i execute the following line, its prints the words in newline. 
awk 'BEGIN { print "line one\nline two\nline three" }' 
like
line one
line two
line three

How can i print the info in the same line with flush the existing line. For example, while executing the loop, it should print 'one' then wipe out the line and prints 'two' then wipe out the line and prints 'three' etc. can you please assist me?

Answer (score 1):

Use carriage return instead of newline

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "line one\rline two\rline three" }'
```

If a subsequent line is shorter than a previous line, you can print spaces to wipe out the remainder:

```
awk 'BEGIN { print "this is a long line of text\rpad with spaces            " }'
```

If you are using separate statements, then you should use `printf` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 0):

What environment are you using to view your output? Putty?
You may need to reconfigure Putty to honor \n "newLines".
OR if your really in Windows/DOS mode, you need

```
printf "line 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3\r\n"
```

Hope this helps.

As you're a new user, just a gentle reminder to accept the answer that works for you, or at least add a vote to answers that help you're understanding.